# Visual Studio 2015 - Application is in break mode - Access Violation Exception (in External Code)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

having a strange problem, during compiling WinForm-Apps. Too often appears an access violation exception, also with a totally empty WinForm-Projekt newly created:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

It occurs here:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
EXCEPTION >>> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(int msg, int wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x44 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateWindowIcon(bool redrawFrame) + 0x111 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle() + 0x2f9 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle.get() + 0x65 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunParkingWindowThread() + 0xb6 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x160 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x17 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x52 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x52 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Running a freshly installed Win8.1 64bit system with VS2015 Enterprise (v14.0.25123.00 Update 2)

Also tried:
- Changing several exception settings (Enable Just My Code, Disable JIT, etc.)

Nothings helped so far.

Can anyone help me please? Working with this issue is nearly impossible ... :(

Comment: You compiling x86 if that happens right? Got such a problem with wpf projects.. I can compile them on x86 but as soon as I run it I got an access violation. What helps here is to start Visual Studio in admin mode.

Comment: Compiling in any target (Any CPU, X64, X86, ...), also VS running as admin; the problem occurs. :(

Comment: Running as Admin is not a solution for me either, as I am having the same issues.  One workaround I've found has been to run it without debugger (CTRL+F5), but I need the debugger at this time in development.  If anyone has found a solution with debugger, please add an answer to this post!

Comment: Same to me.But, what seem to help is: create a blank new project and copy only the relevant code files to the new project directory. This helped me out ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I think I've found the workaround.
I tried uncheking "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process", and it works.